# Spring security use of @PreAuthorize

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-security

Recently I have been working on a a requirement where in certain UI elements should be only visible to user with particular role(say role is XXX)

I used:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('XXX')"> <input type="button"/></sec:authorize>
```

which works fine.

But I just wanted to understand if I need to add the below line as well on the java code? If yes, then why?

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('XXX')")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually, it depends.

If you are building/maintaining a classic MVC application with `Spring MVC` and all of your `RequestMapping`'s are pointing to a (JSP) view (hence resolved by an `InternalResourceViewResolver` and usually rendered by the `JspServlet`) you don't need `@PreAuthorize`.

But, if you are exposing at least one endpoint e.g. as JSON/XML you'll need at add `@PreAuthorize` if it is required.

Simply put, if your handler method returns a value that gets resolved by a [`ViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) use the appropriate tag for [`JSP`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/taglibs.html#taglibs-authorize), [`Velocity`](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/92802-security-jsptaglibs-in-velocity-templates) or [`Freemarker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347589/checking-spring-security-roles-and-logged-username-in-freemarker-template) otherwise consider using `@PreAuthorize`.